# Sony Vaio FW350 reboots instead of waking up after sleep/suspend

Tags: video, suspend, suspend-resume, hdmi, reboot

After I suspend and try to wake up my laptop it just automatically reboots every time. I had this problem in 11.04, but it happened occasionaly. Now I'm with 11.10 and it occurs every time.

It is a sony vaio FW350. It has an onboard Intel graphics.

I also have this other problem since 9.10: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1448330 I guess they are related problems.

Comment: This simple solution was the only that worked for me:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1248737/laptop-shuts-down-instead-of-suspending-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-20-04-when-on

Answer (score 17):

The fix provided in this [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1556934) solved my problem:

1. You just have to edit the `/etc/default/grub` file:

   ```
   gksu gedit /etc/default/grub
   ```
2. Look up the line where it says:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
   ```

   and change it to:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_sleep=nonvs"
   ```
3. Save the file and close gedit.
4. Update the GRUB menu:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
5. Reboot and enjoy!

Comment: It worked also for Ubuntu 16.04, on a Sony Vaio VGN-FW31E!

Comment: It worked also for Ubuntu 20.04