# Suspend, ubuntu 12.04 Sony Vaio VGN-NW120J

Tags: 12.04, suspend, vaio

I've install 12.04 on my Vaio as a second OS.  I created 2 new partitions for `swap` and `/`.

When the lid is closed, system fails in suspend mode. The indicator blinks like it does in Windows (by powered on it is green, on suspend links orange).

But when I start the system again by pressing any key, it looks like normal boot. No changes are saved.

What can be the problem? P.S all updates are installed.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: Please provide excerpt from your syslog, this should narrow down the problem.

Comment: May be there is too much...but here is syslog - http://pastebin.com/r5EE3P3x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about the specifics of which Sony Vaio model this will work for, but it seems this question may be a duplicate of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/67130/29020), which has at least one answer for some Sony Vaio models.