# Resuming problem after suspending

Tags: suspend

I installed ubuntu 12.04 alongside Win7 on "sony vaio fw590gjb". My laptop don't resume after suspending. What is the problem?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to AskUbuntu!  It would be helpful if you could provide us with an idea of what DOES happen when you resume.  Does it go to a black screen?  Does it reboot suddenly?  There are several very similar questions regarding VAIOs that I was able to find in regards to this kind of behavior, and if you search for "Suspend" and "VAIO" you might those suggestions help or resolve your issue, as they are generic (all-user) solutions.

Comment: Hi, thank you for answer. when my VAIO is in suspend mode, with pressing any key, the laptop will reboot from beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to see if the [fix outlined here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67130/sony-vaio-fw350-reboots-instead-of-waking-up-after-sleep-suspend) resolves your issue.

It appears to have fixed the problem for a similar make, but different specific model numbers for other VAIO users with very similar problems (rebooting instead of resuming).

(credit to user Felipe Hummel, but reposting the steps in case future links break)

===

You just have to edit the `/etc/default/grub` file:

(in a terminal window do the following):

`gksu gedit /etc/default/grub`

Look up the line where it says:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

and change it to:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_sleep=nonvs"`

Save the file and close gedit.

Update the GRUB menu by typing in:

`sudo update-grub`

Reboot and enjoy!

===

Comment: Hey gravity your answer fixed my problem. Very very thank you my friend.

Comment: Very welcome, it was a shot in the dark though!  ;)

Comment: Yes exactly, I had this problem for 2 years but now I am happy and indebted to you. My English is bad, sorry for my bad English.