# Upgraded from 18.04 to 18.10, now suspend doesn't work anymore

Tags: suspend, 18.10

I upgraded from 18.04 to 18.10 using the standard procedure, and now whenever I suspend my laptop it actually shuts down.

I notice this only after I press the button to "un-suspend", because I see the whole boot process happening from the start.

Any idea on how I could fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I seem to have fixed this by following the instructions in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/74990/319263), even though they are from 7 years ago...

Edit the following line in the `/etc/default/grub` file:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Change it to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_sleep=nonvs"
```

Save the file, then run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

and reboot.

I wonder why I didn't need to do this with 18.04 and it became necessary only since 18.10.

Comment: This suggests it is for VAIO users? Is this more general than that? https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management/Suspend_and_hibernate#VAIO_users

Comment: @ColinD my laptop is a Dell XPS 13 so I'd say it's a more general issue

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the excellent answer, @wil93.  I took that and made a script that I could
run on my various (about 8) ubuntu-based boxen:

```
if sed -e '/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=\"quiet splash\"/s/splash/& acpi_sleep=nonvs/' /etc/default/grub >junk
then                                                        
  mv junk /etc/default/grub                                 
  update-grub                                               
  echo 'SUCCESS!'                                           
else                                                        
  echo ' *** FAILURE'                                       
fi
```