# No suspend on lid close

Tags: suspend, power-management, laptop, 18.10

I recently noted that my Thinkpad X1 Yoga (1st Generation) will not enter the suspend mode any more when I close the lid of the notebook.
I updated from Ubuntu 18.04.2 to 18.10 recently but I am not 100% sure if the error occured right after the update.

What I have checked:

1. I checked that my `/etc/default/grub` was not changed since I last configured it:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
   ```
2. I changed the `/etc/default/grub` following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1086795/upgraded-from-18-04-to-18-10-now-suspend-doesnt-work-anymore) hint (no effect):

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_sleep=nonvs"
   ```
3. I changed `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` to the following. I edited the Inhibit-entries to "yes" (no effect):

   ```
   [Login]
   HandlePowerKey=hibernate
   HandleHibernateKey=hibernate
   HandleSuspendKey=suspend-then-hibernate
   HandleLidSwitch=suspend-then-hibernate
   HandleLidSwitchDocked=suspend
   PowerKeyIgnoreInhibited=yes
   SuspendKeyIgnoreInhibited=yes
   HibernateKeyIgnoreInhibited=yes
   LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=yes
   ```
4. I thought about the sleep mode itself being broken. But executing `sudo pm-suspend` in terminal will correctly initiate the suspend mode. The screen is getting dark and the power LED is flashing after a few seconds.
5. I checked if the lid sensor itself is broken. Since the Thinkpad uses a magetic sensor in the base and has a magnet in the lid, I tried to trigger the sensor with an external magnet. The sensor seems to work. When moving the magnet over the sensor, the screen turns black. But nothing else happens, the power LED is still on. When removing the magnet, the screen is on again.
6. (update) I also tested `sudo pm-suspend-hybrid` to check if the hybrid suspend mode is broken. This was not the case. The machine entered the suspend mode as expected (screen black + Power led flashing

   (update) free -h gives the following output:

   ```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
   Mem:       7,2Gi       1,7Gi       3,7Gi       674Mi       1,8Gi       4,6Gi
   Swap:      9,0Gi          0B       9,0Gi
   ```

Do you have any more ideas how to get the suspend mode working again? I would like to trigger the new suspend-then-hibernate mode on lid close.

Comment: And how is your RAM and with this update a lot could go wrong?

Comment: I'm afraid i do not understand. I've got 8GB of RAM. An Idea: is it possible that the suspend ist working, but suspend-then-hibernate is not. Is there a terminal command which initiates the suspend-then-hibernate mode?

Comment: Make sure your RAM isn't been used up And leaving nothing for hibernation. Check with `free -h`

Comment: Original post edited: marked with (update)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After performing another Core update for Ubuntu, it is working again.

It seems like there were modifications on the suspend mode or in one of the drivers. I checked the release notes for Ubuntu 18.10 and found nothing, but it looks like there were changes anyway.