# Laptop shuts down instead of suspending after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04 when on battery

Tags: suspend, 20.04, acpi

I just yesterday upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 (coming from 19.10).
Everything is working fine, except, that now when I send the laptop into suspend (no matter if closing the lid, using the menu or `sudo pm-suspend`) the laptop will instead just shut down. This only happens when no AC is plugged in!

Checking `journalctl` gives no meaningful insights, it just says **-- Reboot --**.

`dmesg` gives some ACPI errors, maybe this might be interesting?

```
[    0.326742] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP.TDGC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20190816/psargs-330)
[    0.326751] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PG00._ON due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20190816/psparse-529)
[    0.356479] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC failed (AE_ERROR); disabling ASPM
[    0.573782] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.HEC.CHRG], AE_NOT_FOUND (20190816/psargs-330)
[    0.573793] ACPI Error: Aborting method \PNOT due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20190816/psparse-529)
[    0.573797] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.AC._PSR due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20190816/psparse-529)
[    0.573803] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, Error reading AC Adapter state (20190816/ac-115)
[    0.576615] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.HEC.ECAV], AE_NOT_FOUND (20190816/psargs-330)
[    0.576624] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_TZ.TZ00._TMP due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20190816/psparse-529)
[    0.576769] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.HEC.ECAV], AE_NOT_FOUND (20190816/psargs-330)
[    0.576775] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_TZ.TZ00._TMP due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20190816/psparse-529)
[    0.576837] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.HEC.ECAV], AE_NOT_FOUND (20190816/psargs-330)
[    0.576842] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_TZ.TZ01._TMP due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20190816/psparse-529)
[    0.576897] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.HEC.ECAV], AE_NOT_FOUND (20190816/psargs-330)
[    0.576902] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_TZ.TZ01._TMP due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20190816/psparse-529)
[   22.094640] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_GPE._E42.SPRT], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-323)
[   22.094651] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
[   22.094653] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_GPE._E42 due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20190816/psparse-529)
[   22.094657] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_GPE._E42 due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20190816/psparse-529)
[   22.094664] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, while evaluating GPE method [_E42] (20190816/evgpe-511)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution actually was to properly shutdown the computer instead of restarting. So the actual "Power Off" option in Ubuntu. After that, the issue never reoccurred.

Comment: Worked for me as well after updates messed it up on 22.04